# Getting taxonomy terms used by custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, hierarchical

I have a custom post type - **case** - for which I am building an archive page. There are three custom taxonomies for this type - **micro_organisms**, **infection_types**, and **antibiotic_types**. These taxonomies are hierarchical, and have a variety of terms, up to three levels deep. For the given post type, I'm wanting to list terms for, say, the **antibiotic_types** taxonomy, that are used by any **case** entries.

While a term within the **antibiotic_types** taxonomy may be used by any of the **case** entries, I want to show the hierarchy leading to the selected term.

So far, I've got the following working, which results in a flat list of just the selected terms, not reflecting the hierarchy the terms are in.

```
// sourced from:
// http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66015/how-to-get-a-list-of-taxonomy-terms-which-are-being-used-only-within-certain-pos
function get_terms_by_post_type( $taxonomies, $post_types ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) AS count from $wpdb->terms AS t INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS r ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p.ID = r.object_id WHERE p.post_type IN('" . join( "', '", $post_types ) . "') AND tt.taxonomy IN('" . join( "', '", $taxonomies ) . "') GROUP BY t.term_id");
    return $query;
}
?>
...
<ul class="taxonomy-term-list">
<?php
$terms = get_terms_by_post_type(array($tax), array('case'));

foreach ($terms as $term):
    $termData = get_term_by('id', $term->term_id, $tax);
    $termName = $termData->name;
    $termUrl = get_term_link($termData);
?>
    <li class="taxonomy-term"><a href="<?php echo $termUrl; ?>?post_type=<?php echo $type; ?>"><?php echo $termName; ?> (<?php echo $term->count; ?>)</a></li>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

The output resembles:

- penicillin-g
- ceftriaxone
- amphotericin-b
- 5-flucytosine

While the desired output is:

- beta-lactams

  - cephalosporins

    - ceftriaxone
  - penicillins

    - penicillin-g
- antifungals

  - amphotericin-b
  - 5-flucytosine

I've also tried using the following:

```
wp_list_categories(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'antibiotic_types',
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'title_li' => ''
    )
);
```

Which shows *all* of the terms for the given taxonomy, even those not used by any **case** entries.

Having browsed the function reference, it doesn't look as if there is any built-in function for doing what I want to achieve, not directly anyway. I haven't done much with taxonomy queries until now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a custom walker?
http://www.paulund.co.uk/display-categories-of-a-custom-post-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see doc for [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) in codex, you'll se that it accepts a `include` param, that should contain a comma separed list of categorys ids.

So if you change your function `get_terms_by_post_type` creating the function `get_terms_id_by_post_type` to retrieve only the term ids, just like:

```
function get_terms_id_by_post_type( $taxonomies, $post_types ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT t.term_id from $wpdb->terms AS t INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS r ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p.ID = r.object_id WHERE p.post_type IN('" . join( "', '", $post_types ) . "') AND tt.taxonomy IN('" . join( "', '", $taxonomies ) . "') GROUP BY t.term_id");
    return $query;
}
```

Then you can:

```
// retrieve the term ids used by post type
$terms = get_terms_id_by_post_type( array($tax), array('case') );

// if that terms exist implode in a commasepared string
$term_list = ! empty($terms) ? implode(',', $terms) : false;

// use wp_list_categories with include param to included only used terms
if ( $term_list ) {
  wp_list_categories(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'antibiotic_types',
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'title_li' => '',
        'include' => $term_list
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Good tip on the include parameter. I hadn't thought of using that to limit the function results to the current terms. With some additional code I was able to assemble a function to handle the work for me.

Comment: With a minor caveat: for the hierarchical terms to appear in tree form, it is necessary to assign any ancestor terms to content along with a targeted term. Otherwise the result was a flat list. So for the `penicillin-g` term, I also needed to use the `penicillins` and `beta-lactams` terms.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else googling around needs to only show terms from one taxonomy used by CPT posts set to another taxonomy, here's the code I used for that, based on the answer by @gmazzap:

```
// Get all story post IDs set to story_type of "rn"
$story_post_ids = get_posts([
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'fields'      => 'ids',
  'post_type'   => 'story',
  'tax_query'   => [
    [
      'taxonomy' => 'story_type',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => ['rn'],
      'compare'  => 'IN',
    ]
  ],
]);

// Find story topics in use by those post IDs
$story_topic_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
      SELECT t.term_id FROM $wpdb->terms AS t
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS r ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
      WHERE tt.taxonomy IN('story_topic')
      AND r.object_id IN (".implode(',', $story_post_ids).")
      GROUP BY t.term_id
");

// Pull those topics
$story_topics = get_terms([
  'taxonomy' => 'story_topic',
  'include'  => $story_topic_ids,
]);
```

This finds all terms of type `story_topic` that are in use by posts set to the term `story_type` of "rn."