# How to get list of custom taxonomies based on custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I have 2 custom post types and custom taxonomy assigned to both post types.

On the page where I list posts (custom post type archive page) I would like to dispay a list of all custom taxonomy terms that are assigned to posts in this post type.

I did this with `wp_list_categories` but it lists ALL terms and not just the ones populated with posts from this post type.

```
function taxonomy_term_list() {
    $taxonomy     = 'my_taxonomy';
    $orderby      = 'name';
    $show_count   = 1;
    $pad_counts   = 1;
    $hierarchical = 1;
    $title        = '';
    $empty        = 1;

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
        'orderby'      => $orderby,
        'show_count'   => $show_count,
        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'title_li'     => $title,
        'hide_empty'   => $empty
    );

    echo wp_list_categories( $args );

}
```

Is there any way I can pass `post_type` argument here?

Answer (score 0):

Yo might want to have a look at this post:

- [Getting taxonomy terms used by custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118861/getting-taxonomy-terms-used-by-custom-post-type)

You can include the empty terms by passing `'hide_empty' => 0,`.

Comment: Solution on link seems to output also terms that have posts from other post type. I just need to have a list of terms that have posts in this post type.